# Merge latest version of a branch into its root with Team Foundation Version Control in Team Foundation Server

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control, branching-and-merging

We are having problems trying to do a merge using Team Foundation Version Control from Visual Studio 2017, and we don´t know if it´s posible or even sensible to do it as we want to.

I am going to explain a simplified version of my problem:

We have a root branch in Source Control, let´s call it Root, and we have a branch of Root that I will call Branch.

We are commiting changes to Branch and when we are sure we want them on Root we Merge from Branch to Root (we do a Reverse Integration). Thing is, we did some merge in the past where we selected only a subset of the Changesets in Branch to merge them into Root.

Now, after some other changes in Branch, we know that the latest version we have of Branch is working and we want to merge that version into Root.

The problem is that when we are doing the merge, it takes the version of a file as it was on the last changeset that modified that file AND that changeset was not merged into Root. But we know that the last version of that file in Branch is the version we want, even though it doesn´t appear because the changeset that let it in that state could have been previously merged (in fact, most of the tiemes, the last version of that file in Branch and Root are identical, and we don´t want change that).

Example:

We make Changeset 1 into Branch and we merge it to Root.

We make Changeset 2 into Branch, modifying File1 (but we don´t merge it into Root).

We make Changeset 3 into Branch, modifying File1 again, and we merge it into Root. Now Branch and Root have the same version of File.

We make Changeset 4, 5, 6 into Branch, unrelated to File1.

Now what we want to do is merge the latest version of any file AS IT IS NOW in Branch, into Root.

But if I try to merge Branch into Root, it will prompt that there is a conflict, and what it will show in the Conflict Resolver is:

File1 as it was after Changeset 2 as the source (that is the version of the file as it was after the last Changeset not merged into Root), and

File1 as it is in the Root as the target (and that happens to be the exact same version of the File1 that I have in the last version of Branch, and I want to keep that way).

By the way, it doesn´t matter if we mark "Select all changes up to..." with Latest Version, Changeset (using the latest), Date (now), Workspace, etc.. or "Selected changesets" and then we select everything (of course, previously merged ones doesn´t appear here anyway).
Is that some way to tell Source Control that we want to merge the latest version of every file in Branch into Root, regardless of wether the changeset was previously merged or not? Does all this makes any sense at all or am I missing something?

Comment: Have you checked and tried the suggestions mentioned in below answer? Does that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

The TFS merge engine relies on history, not file contents. You may check `tf merge /candidate` command to list the changesets in the source that have not yet been merged into the destination. And use `tf merge /version` to merge the changes. Check the link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/merge-command?view=azure-devops

By the way, there will always have situation that you have to manually merge.